# Error while installing Office Outlook Add-In created with yo generator

Tags: office-js

i've created a Office Outlook Extension via YO Generator. When debugging the Add-In via local server with "npm start" everthing works like expected. After publishing the add-in to a azure storage container i am getting the following error when i try to install the add-in.

> Diese App kann nicht installiert werden. Die Manifest-XML-Datei ist ungültig. For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.

> This app cannot be installed. The manifest XML file is invalid. For security reasons, the DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing, set the DtdProcessing property in XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings to the XmlReader.Create method.